# Handling exceptions that are (re)thrown by Picasso

Tags: java, android, picasso

Is it possible to catch exceptions like these? Can I use Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler?

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: RemoteViews for widget update exceeds maximum bitmap memory usage (used: 1000000, max: 921600) The total memory cannot exceed that required to fill the device's screen once.
       at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1429)
       at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1379)
       at com.android.internal.appwidget.IAppWidgetService$Stub$Proxy.updateAppWidgetIds(IAppWidgetService.java:523)
       at android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(AppWidgetManager.java:333)
       at com.squareup.picasso.RemoteViewsAction$AppWidgetAction.update(RemoteViewsAction.java:99)
       at com.squareup.picasso.RemoteViewsAction.complete(RemoteViewsAction.java:43)
       at com.squareup.picasso.Picasso.deliverAction(Picasso.java:511)
       at com.squareup.picasso.Picasso.complete(Picasso.java:470)
       at com.squareup.picasso.Picasso$1.handleMessage(Picasso.java:115)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4963)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

I see that Picasso is throwing exceptions using Handler:

```
Picasso.HANDLER.post(new Runnable() { ...
```

Is it possible to catch this exceptions from my code?

Comment: Since Picasso loads images asynchronously if it's not in the cache, you can't catch it's exceptions from your code. If you set up a global `UncaughtExceptionHandler` on the main thread, then you can of course catch all unchecked exceptions and handle them as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

In **developer** site:

> The total Bitmap memory used by the RemoteViews object cannot exceed
>   that required to fill the screen 1.5 times, ie. (screen width x screen
>   height x 4 x 1.5) bytes.

In your particular case the error occurs when a bitmap loading from stream is larger than possible.

You need to decode the image after comparison for proper size for your layout!

or via `.resize(imageWidth, imageHight)` on Picasso library !

Hope this help :) ..

Comment: I've done it already (I've forgotten to add resize) but I am just curious if it is possible to catch exceptions that are thrown by Picasso to main thread. I want to this error and not crash my app ;-)

Comment: so what about try{..}catch (Exception e) 
 {
 e.printStackTrace();
 } mmm ??!